# webpage graphic editor

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I would like to integrate to my website project a graphic editor like a webpage or layout editor in order to put some objects on an image background. For example write text on that image, insert images and so on. Any ideas? third party libraries could be proper solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML5 Canvas](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#divingin) will support all of these things that you mention. It depends what type of cross browser support you want and fallback options. People have created demos of 'whiteboard' type plugins and the like.